# How to automatically remove *.hot-update.json files when using react-hot-loader package?

Tags: webpack, react-hot-loader

I have a series of hot loader files (*.hot-loader.json) building up in my output directory. How can I ensure that this output directory cleans out the unecessary files?

Note: I am also using Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`webpack-middleware-dev`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), as these files will be loaded in memory rather than on disk.

[`webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) uses `webpack-middleware-dev` automatically.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and using `webpack-middleware-dev`. I'm also using `browser-sync` instead of `webpack-dev-server` and wondering if the @joetidee is as well?

Comment: I'm using `webpack-dev-server` without `react-hot-loader`, `browser-sync` and have the same problem, could you provide more details ?